# find pojo fields by annotation name

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, spring-boot

I had below code I am using Spring.:

```
 @Entity
@Table(name = "bigcommerce_newsletter_subscriber")
public class BigcommerceNewsletterSubscriberData implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "account_store_id")
    private Integer accountStoreId;

    @Column(name = "subsciber_id")
    @DataTableHeader(displayName="ID", order=1)
    private Integer subsciberId;

    @Column(name = "email")
    @DataTableHeader(displayName="Email", order=4)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    @DataTableHeader(displayName="First Name", order=2)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    @DataTableHeader(displayName="Last Name", order=3)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "source")
    @DataTableHeader(displayName="Source", order=6)
    private String source;
```

now I want all field which contains @DataTableHeader annotation with this annotation.I don't have idea how can I get this. can enyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with java reflection

```
for(Field field : BigcommerceNewsletterSubscriberData.class.getDeclaredFields()){
  Annotation[] annotations = field.getDeclaredAnnotationsByType(DataTableHeader.class);
  if (annotations.length > 0)
    System.out.println(field.getName());
}
```

Just filter fields, that have annotation you want.

Comment: I want list of fields which contains @DataTableHeader annotation will it return list of fields? i am not getting perfactly so if you can clearify how it will return then please....

Comment: edited comment. Please check it

Comment: ok thank you i'll cheack it

Comment: @HardikSiroya please mark this answer as resolution after you test it

Answer (score 2):

We can use [`Class#getDeclaredFields()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields()) to get all fields as `Field[]`. With [`Field#getAnnotations()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#getAnnotations()), we can get all annotations of one specific field as `Annotation[]`.

With the help of these two methods, the problem is solvable. Below is a sample implementation using Java 8 [`Stream`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) and [`Predicate`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html).

```
List<Field> allFields = 
    Arrays.asList(BigcommerceNewsletterSubscriberData.class.getFields());
Predicate<Field> isAnnotated = 
    field -> Arrays.asList(field.getAnnotations()).contains(DataTableHeader.class);
List<Field> annotatedFields = allFields.stream()
        .filter(isAnnotated)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Please keep in mind though that [`Collectors.toList()` does not guarantee that the returned `List` is mutable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList()).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `reflections` library that provides a set of utilities for doing reflections in Java. To obtain a list of fields that contains a certain annotations, you can try this :

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("my.project");
Set<Field> fields = reflections.getFieldsAnnotatedWith(DataTableHeader .class);
```

If you are using maven, try add this to your pom dependencies :

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
   <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.11</version>
</dependency>
```